# In Windows 8, where to manage shell context menu commands associated with file types?

Tags: windows-8, shell, context-menu, file-association

Maybe this is a duplicate, but I cannot guess the correct teminology to find answer if it was posted already.

**Where in Windows 8 can I open the user inteface to add/edit/remove shell context menu commands associated with some file type?**

I do not mean registry editing. I remember there was a way via dialog boxes in Windows XP.

Example: for PDF document, these are `Open` and `Print`:

[image]

*I will also accept an answer illustrated on Windows 10 if the same steps will work for me on Windows 8. Some of us remember that Windows 10 was created only by renaming oncoming release of Windows 8.2. :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seacrhing more sources, I think I found the answer.

Although the editor [did exist up to Windows XP](https://web.archive.org/web/20121012081438/http://annoyances.org/exec/show/article02-026)

> **File Types** window > **Advanced** button > **Actions** button

it seems *no longer* to be part of the Windows user interface.

The only possibilities seem to use either the registry ([complete reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171(v=vs.85).aspx)) or some [3rd party editors](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-click-context-menu-items-editors).